# Como llamar a una funcion en tiempo de ejecucion en c

Tags: c, funciones

Por ejemplo con este pseudocódigo

```
   function suma(a,b)
    {
    return a+b
    }

    function callfun(namefunction,arg1,arg2)
    {
    namefunction(arg1,arg2)
    }
```

tambien nesesito saber como hacer una consola y
    desde la consola escribo esto para llamar a la funcion suma

```
callfun(suma,3,3)
```

Comment: Pregunta **muy**, **muy** amplia. Da casi para un libro.

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta corta: No *pero* Si.

Respuesta larga:

Lo que propones es propio de lenguajes *interpretados*, que pueden 
localizar funciones **por nombre** en tiempo de ejecución.

C es *compilado*, y no permite *de fábrica* hacer lo que indicas.
No obstante, es posible una aproximación, pero con **punteros a funciones**

```
void function1( int a ) {
  ...
}

void call( void ( *f )( int ), int v ) {
  *f( v );
}

void ( *ptr )( int ) = function1;
call( ptr, 10 );
```

Para seleccionar una entra varias funciones, puedes usar una structura y un arreglo:

```
struct ident {
  char *name;
  void ( *ptr )( void );
};
struct ident functions[];
```

Y recorres el arreglo buscando el nombre indicado.

Y, si quieres más flexibilidad, pues utilizas funciones con argumentos variables:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void funct( const char *fmt, ... ) {
  va_list ap;

  va_start( ap, fmt );
  ...
  va_end( ap );
}
```

y declaras el puntero como

```
void ( *pointer )( const char *, ... );
```

Creo que con lo anterior ya puedes ir tirando algún código para mostrarnos ...

Comment: Si, cierto, no es una respuesta, pero es que era muy largo para un comentario xD

Answer (score 2):

Las funciones siempre se llaman en tiempo de ejecución, eso es cuando se abre el programa.

Para la suma es fácil, en vez de `function`, debería ser `float`, y los parámetros `a` y `b` deberían ser `float` también, ya que es una suma de números reales.

```
float suma(float a,float b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

La función `callfun`, como no tiene la sentencia `return`, devuelve un `void`, pero los parámetros, no se sabe de qué tipo son, así que los nombro, `Tipo_1_1`, `Tipo_1_2`, `Tipo_1_3`, `Tipo_2` y `Tipo_3`, pero podría ser cualquier tipo de dato, `void`, `int`, `char`.

```
void callfun(Tipo_1_1 (*namefunction)(Tipo_1_2,Tipo_1_3),Tipo_2 arg1,Tipo_3 arg2)
{
    (*namefunction)(arg1,arg2);
}
```

Para llamarla sería lo siguiente, solo hay que agregar un punto y coma `;`.

```
callfun(suma,3,3);
```